# 韓国語メールフォームをbase64でエンコードしたが、確認メールを入力した言語（韓国語）で受け取りたい

Tags: php, mail

フルスクラッチではなく、元々日本語用メールフォームの改造で、韓国語用メールフォームを作成しております。

```
$MAIL_SUBJECT = '自動送信メールのタイトル';
$MAILTO = $in[email];
$FH = fopen('送信するメールのひな形.mail',"r");
$MAIL_MESS = fread ($FH,1000000);
fclose($FH);
//----メール記載内容
$MAIL_MESS = str_replace("[st_date]",$in[st_date],$MAIL_MESS);
//----エンコード指定
mb_language("uni");
$MAIL = base64_encode($MAIL_MESS);

//$MAIL_SUBJECT = JcodeConvert($MAIL_SUBJECT,0,3);
$sender_name = 'メーラーに表示される送信者名';
$Header = "From: ".mb_encode_mimeheader($sender_name). " <{$ADMIN_MAIL}>\nCC: {$ADMIN_MAIL}\n";
if(!mb_send_mail($MAILTO,$MAIL_SUBJECT,$MAIL,$Header)){
    $val = "Not send mail";
    setcookie("inb_err_msg[email]","$val",0,"/");
    header("Location: form.html");
    exit();
}
```

と、base64にエンコードすることで文字化けせずメールは受信出来るようなったのですが、
本文が（当然ですが）base64でエンコードされたものになっています。
どうにか入力した言語（韓国語）で受け取りたいのですが、どのような記述が必要なのでしょうか。

Comment: コード部分を追記しました。

Comment: このコードを見るかぎり `base64_encode` さえしなければ良さそうなんですが、そうする前にはどういう文字化けをしていましたか？ メールのひな形ファイルも関係あるのかな。文字コードは utf-8 ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
エンコードをしないと、普通の（？）文字化けでメールが届いてしまうのです。文字コードはutf-8です。

Comment: 具体的には`$MAIL = base64_encode($MAIL_MESS);`を`$MAIL = $MAIL_MESS;`にしたり、header指定部分を`$Header = "From: ".mb_encode_mimeheader($sender_name). " <{$ADMIN_MAIL}>\nCC: {$ADMIN_MAIL}\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding:BASE64\n";`としてみましたが、うまくいきませんでした

Answer (score 4):

メールのヘッダーに

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

と指定します。これにより、メーラーが base64 デコードして画面に表示してくれます。
参考： [日本語メールの仕組み | SendGridブログ](https://sendgrid.kke.co.jp/blog/?p=10958)

[`mb_send_mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-send-mail.php) ではメールヘッダを4番目の引数 (`additional_headers`) に指定しますが、
その前に [`mb_language("uni")`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-language.php) と書いているのでむしろ自前で base64_encode したり `Content-Transfer-Encoding` 指定する必要はないかもしれません。

もうちょっと広い範囲のプログラムコードや、PHPのバージョン、あとこのコードで実際に受け取ったメールのヘッダ部分を提示してくださるとなんか分かるかもしれません。

Comment: ご丁寧な返答ありがとうございます。
追記いたします。

Comment: メールのヘッダーには
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
となっております。